# Fetch value of dictionary from JSON

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I want to fetch values of string from JSON , I am able to parse JSON to Dictionary but not able to convert into array of string

FROM SERVER

```
    {
        “ALL TEXT: [

  { 
    "text": "hello"
   },
   {
    "text": "hi"
   },
    {
    "text": "how r u"
    }
]
  }
```

I only want value of text to append to my string array "textsList"

```
    var textsList : [String]()
```

This is what I had tried

```
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in                               
                   let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                   
             
                let AllText = json[“ALL TEXT”] as!  [Dictionary<String, Any>]
                let value = JSON(AllText)
                
                AllText.forEach { fetch in
                  self.textsList.append(fetch.values) // ERROR no exact matches in call to instance method append
                                    }

           for(key, object) in value{
           print(value)  //output:  {"text": "hello" },{"text": "hi" }
           print(value.string)  //output:nil
            }

    
                   
               }.resume()
```

I just want to convert dictionary into array , but also alternate solution to convert JSON directly into array of string will be fine.

Comment: I doubt you have a dictionary returned from json. You have a list of an anon class that has a text prop.

Comment: If you truly have a dictionary then use the Values[] property. It will return a List of strings.

Comment: @TMcKeown I think you are mixing up C# and Swift. The OP is asking about Swift and your comments refer to C# concepts (anon classes and the `Values[]` property of dictionaries)

Comment: Ah. I thought this was c#. Haha ok thx

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the code:

```
    let string = """
        {
            "ALL TEXT": [
          {
            "text": "hello"
           },
           {
            "text": "hi"
           },
            {
            "text": "how r u"
            }
        ]
      }
  """
    
    guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8),
    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
    let allText = json["ALL TEXT"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>]
        else {
        DDLog("json fail")
        return }
    DDLog(allText) // [["text": hello], ["text": hi], ["text": how r u]]
    
    let items: [String] = allText.compactMap { $0["text"] as? String }
    
    var textsList = [String]()
    textsList.append(contentsOf: items)

    DDLog(items) //["hello", "hi", "how r u"]
    DDLog(textsList) //["hello", "hi", "how r u"]
```

Two errors：

```
1. <"ALL TEXT> Missing right quote；
2. var textsList: [String]() =》var textsList = [String]()；
```

Comment: The line `let items: [String] = allText.map { $0["text"] }.compactMap { ($0 as! String) }` will crash if the JSON object did not contain a "text" key because of the force unwrap (`as!`). You can simplify the line and fix the crash by changing it to `let items: [String] = allText.compactMap { $0["text"] as? String }`

Comment: Your code is better, I have adjusted the code, thank you very much!@idz

Comment: Just one more thing... there's no real need (as far as I can see) to create a new copy of `items` in `textList`. Otherwise, nice answer!

Comment: I am not sure if the textsList in the question is a global variable. The returned result may be a menu that needs to be displayed elsewhere.@idz

Comment: I am able to get array of string from your solution also but I am still getting error of no exact matches in call to instance method append